# Group management system to replace BigTent

Tags: web-apps

My wife is the membership coordinator for our [local twins club](http://www.ttmom.org/). Currently, they use [BigTent](http://www.bigtent.com/), which seems ideally suited to the task from the sales pitch:

- It keeps track of who has joined and who has paid their dues.
- Members can enter information on their children, such as names and birthdates.
- When people are ready to pay dues, BigTent offers credit card processing.
- There are features like event calendars, forums and emailed newsletters.

Unfortunately, the backend is difficult to use and flaky. Last weekend, they had an event and several people reported problems logging into BigTent to pay dues. Nobody can figure out how to pay from the site; you have to get an email with a special link.  Finally, the club needs to keep a separate spreadsheet to track memberships because BigTent assumes different membership rules than the club does.

The club has mostly moved to their Facebook group for communication, so they don't need the forum or calendar features. But they do need a system for tracking member information and a service allowing dues to be paid with a credit card. BigTent could be replaced with a multiple services, but they ought to work well together.

Comment: Did you find a recommendation to replace BigTent?  We're looking for something similar.

Comment: @MikePone: Sadly no. My wife has moved on to volunteering with Cub Scouts and they have their own system. It's slightly better than BigTent because it's customized to the Scouts' processes. But there don't seem to be better options for the more general case. :-(